# Add values to the same variable loop jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I need to calcultate the value of dynamics price field and save it to my logs with jQuery.

The user can add fields by pressin a button. This part of the code is already working with auto-increment, etc.

**Here is my code.**

```
<input name="value_1" min="0" class="versement_each" id="booking_1" autocomplete="off" readonly="readonly" type="text"/></div>
```

I am using the class versement_each to start my loop.

```
function calculateVersements()
    {
        var versement_each = 0;

        $('.versement_each').each(function()
        {
            versement_each = parseFloat($(this).val() + versement_each).toFixed(2);

        });

        console.log(versement_each);
    }
```

My code is woking at like 50% since it does calculate, but only takes the first value.

Also, can you tell my if my way to transform my output data to 00.00 is OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function calculateVersements() {
    var versement_each = 0;
    $('.versement_each').each(function () {
        versement_each += parseFloat(this.value) || 0;

    });
    console.log(versement_each.toFixed(2));
}
```

Comment: This code is working good for now! If I understand it correctly, the || 0 is only a condition to avoid the value = 0 ?

Comment: The `|| 0` is used so that the `NaN` values can be escaped

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$('.versement_each').each(function()
{
    versement_each = versement_each + parseFloat(this.value);
});
```

Or even better:

```
$('.versement_each').each(function()
{
    versement_each += parseFloat(this.value);
});
```

And only after you've computed the sum, convert it back to a string:

```
versement_each = versement_each.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: `versement_each += newValue` is the way to go, so the first is not needed at all. Also instead of `$(this).val()` -> `this.value` is much... JS?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan That's a very good point about `this.value`. I included the first option simply because some visitors might not be familiar with compound assignment, and I wanted to demonstrate that they are equivalent.

Comment: I think this way could actually works good, but it seems only to "stack" all the data so I could have the result 03303300